# Using Office Interop from within App-V, how can I let Excel see the file?

Tags: c#, excel, appv

I've got some code:

```
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(name);
        Excel.Workbook book = 
            ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(file.FullName,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Calling this from within my app when it's run from inside App-V means that Excel complains that the file doesn't exist.  The file is one that's in the same folder as the application (it's a template that's shipped with it), and it looks like Excel is spawned outside of the Bubble, meaning that it can't see anything inside the virtualised file folder.

Anyone managed to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to launch Excel inside the bubble is very simple, you just need to have a custom shortcut for Excel, that adds the following argument:

> /appvve:< PACKAGEGUID_VERSIONGUID >

You can read more in the following article about [launching a process inside a virtual environment](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2848278).